# data retrieving from data base 1 after another in 1 page Django

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django, database

guys i was building an online quiz computation.In the user side i need to display questions 1 at a time onclick next, next question should display.Here i am able to retrieve question from database.But all are displaying in 1 page like i have 1200 questions in total. what functionality and method i need to use here. language - python ; frame-work - django ; database - mysql; frontend - Html, css, javascript .
thanks in advance.

**below attachment is template**

[image]

Comment: you can achieve this with CSS and Javascript. create 1 html container for each question and show and hide that container based on the user action (next/previous).

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and try to edit your question to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.